# How many ticks must I use to get only one item through a hopper?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-bukkit

If I have a powered hopper with items in it, and I want to let one item through, how long do I have to un-power the hopper? 1 or 2 ticks? All I know is that a hopper transfers items at the rate of 2.5 items per second. Any help is appreciated :) And is there a different amount of time on Bukkit servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pistons also have a .5 tick on the end. the game gives off-tick checks to increase speed, to there are 2 game-ticks in every redstone tick. Therefor 8 game-ticks, or 4 redstone ticks.

Answer (score 2):

An item will pass through a hopper every .4 seconds. A Minecraft tick is 1/20th of a second, or 0.05s.

So, that means every 0.4s **8** ticks occur. Therefore, you will need to wait **8 ticks** in order to get 1 item through a hopper.

This holds true for Bukkit servers as well.

Comment: Note that redstone devices run on 1/10 second steps, not 1/20.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: So it's 8 server ticks, or 4 redstone ticks (which is also the max. amount on a repeater)

Comment: @alexanderpas Yes. lotsa math...

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the configuration of the server. I recommend using comparator to check if the item got inside of the hopper and lock it.

Answer (score 0):

2.5 blocks per second so let's see. We know that one second is 10 redstone ticks so if we divide 10 by 2.5 then we should get how long it takes for one to pass through. This would equal 4 ticks or four tenths of a second.

Answer (score -1):

1 block = 1 second = 1 tick.

The exact game ticks will be a little different but this way overcompensates a little to make sure you get what you need. If you're not looking for an exact match to the games ticks that is

Comment: What do you mean with "1 second = 1 tick"?